# i want to know the usage of a low pass filter and the usage of the phase

Tags: power-electronics

Good morning.
i would like to know a practical example about low pass filter and high filters..
and whats the use of calculating the phase between the input and output

Comment: Bass and treble controls of a hi-fi is one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low-Pass filter:  Your ADSL line filter so the higher frequency "broadband data" does not impact voice

[image]

Likewise from a power electronics point of view & a PWM inverter, there maybe a need to "smooth out" the higher frequency PWM to produce a sinus voltage

High-Pass filter: These are used in the loud speakers to reduce the low level noise.

Likewise as Andy aka stated: hifi crossover

[image]

Use of calculating phase... depends on the field of interest. Control stability is one, group delay is another. 
You tagged this "power electronics" do you have something specific in mind...